# Symfony - Form works but it's depend

Tags: forms, symfony

I made a form named "searchType" and in a Controller, I call this form. In the route of the method, there is a begin date, an end date and a keyword.

The last parameter of the route is optional, so, my route is as follow :

```
/**
 * @Route({
 *     "en": "/get/list/{end}/{begin}/{keyword}"
 * }, name="get_list")
 */
```

Then my controller method is as follow :

```
public function entreprise_annonce_list(Request $request,  $begin='', $end='', $keyword='')
{
    $search = new Search();
    if(strlen($begin)>0){
        $search->setBegin(\DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y",$begin));
    }
    else{
        $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y","01.10.2018");
        $search->setBegin($date);
    }
    if(strlen($end)>0){
        $search->setEnd(\DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y",$end));
    }
    else{
        $search->setEnd(new \DateTime());
    }
    if(strlen($keyword)>0){
        $search->setSearch($keyword);
    }
    $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $search);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        return $this->redirect(
            $this->generateUrl(
                'get_list', 
                array(
                      'begin'=>$search->getBegin()->format('d.m.Y'),
                      'end'=>$search->getEnd()->format('d.m.Y'),
                      'search'=>$search->getSearch()
                )
            )
        );
    }

    //...

}
```

So if the route match that :

1) works fine : http://localhost:8000/get/list

2) works fine : http://localhost:8000/get/list/17.10.2018/01.10.2018

3) works fine : http://localhost:8000/get/list/17.10.2018/01.10.2018/test

Doesn't work if the route were the last one (no 3) and if I remove the keyword ("test") in my form. The error in the title occurs.

As I see, the error come from the

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

I understand why the error occurs, but I don't know how to correct it.
Could you help me, please :)

I tried to add default parameter in the route, but the same error occurs.

++

Answer (score 0):

The function argument `$search` is immediately overwritten by your first line `$search = new Search();`

Use separate variable names for the search term and the search object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not the problem, I changed the "search" parameter with "keyword" and there is the same issue.